# Is antlr4's golang visitor pattern in a usable state?

Tags: go, antlr4

I see no working examples, and I see a few pull requests that remain open.
I would like to avoid going down the garden path.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/1807

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1843

There are also pull requests that make me think the golang target might be dead in the water.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2152

So all I am really asking is should I steer clear of golang, or is the documentation just somewhere that google doesn't see :-)

Comment: Another worry is that the official documentation  https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/go-target.md  has not been updated in over two years.

Comment: Might be more useful to raise an issue with the same question

Comment: @KarthikNayak, I thought of this, but when I tried I was sent here by the "issue" text.

Comment: OK so I succumbed https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2504

Comment: crickets over there too.

Comment: Not a good sign for using the library.

Comment: a working solution has been given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038949/how-to-write-a-antlr4-visitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To people who don't click on the issue. The visitor pattern is usable. 
I wrote a sample app [here](https://github.com/nikunjy/antlr-calc-go) 
I don't think it is written the way I was supposed to but it does what I wanted it to do. More discussion can be found on the issue and if I learn something new I will change my code.